# perform the same action as device back button React native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have added back button to the app and when I click it I want to perform the same action as that of the device back button. how can I achieve that in react native.

Currently I am on Android.r

Could you share any relevant information regarding this please.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a user press the back button on the device, what the app does is removing the screen at the top of the stack. In react-navigation you can use the "goBack" function to do the same.

Example:

```
onPressBack=()=>{
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
}
```

source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back